# EntityManager injection not working with Tomcat + OpenEJB

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, jsf-2, openejb

I'm using NetBeans IDE 7.1, Apache Tomcat 6.0.26, OpenEJB 3.0 and JSF 2.0. First I insert `openejb.war` into folder: *Apache Tomcat 6.0.26\webapps*. Looks like the Tomcat server works OK, because after running the project the Tomcat server logs:

```
Apache OpenEJB 3.0    build: 20080408-04:13
http://openejb.apache.org/
```

Here is my code:

**GenderManager**

```
@Stateless
public final class GenderManager {
    private final static String QUERY_GET_GENDER = "from Gender gender";
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="ExampleWebPU", name="ExampleWebPU")
    private EntityManager em;
     public List<Gender> getAllGender() {
        try {
            Query query = em.createQuery(QUERY_GET_GENDER);
            return query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**GenderController**

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class GenderController {
    @EJB
    private GenderManager gm;  
    public List<Gender> getAllGender() {
        return gm.getAllGender();
    }
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="ExampleWebPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/db1</jta-data-source>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/db1</non-jta-data-source>
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(foreignKeys=true" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SchemaFactory" value="native(foreignKeys=true)" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.MappingDefaults"
                value="ForeignKeyDeleteAction=restrict, JoinForeignKeyDeleteAction=restrict" />
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=TRACE,SQL=TRACE" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**openejb.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Context>
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127\.0\.0\.1,0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1(%.*)?" deny=""/>
   <openejb>
    <Resource id="db1" type="DataSource">
      JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example_db1
      UserName root
      Password root
      JtaManaged true
    </Resource>
    <Resource id="db2" type="DataSource">
      JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example_db2
      UserName root
      Password root
      JtaManaged true
    </Resource>
  </openejb>
</Context>
```

I did not add extra code. When the line `gm.getAllGender()` in `GenderController` tries to  execute, I get the following exception:

```
javax.el.ELException: /register.xhtml @50,119 value="#{genderController.allGender}": Error reading 'allGender' en el tipo com.example.GenderController
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:129)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.initializeItems(SelectItemsIterator.java:202)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.SelectItemsIterator.hasNext(SelectItemsIterator.java:135)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderOptions(MenuRenderer.java:762)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:844)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:298)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.GenderController.getAllGender(GenderController.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:62)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

An EJB class should not be declared as final. I am wondering how you have been able to compile the `GenderManager` `Stateless` class.
Remove the `final` from `GenderManager` class definition.

Comment: Thanks perissf for the answer. I already remove the final of the class, but didn't work :S.

Comment: The previously code compiled ok, at least nettbeans didn't give me any error or warning, but is nice to know that a EJB class can not be final. I am new in the web world.
Thanks anyway... any suggestion more?

Comment: This is curious, because NetBeans gave me a warning. Anyway, the rest looks fine. Try it. If you have other problems, please ask new questions. If this answer solved your issue, mark it as accepted.

Comment: perissf , I modified the code but didn't work :S. 

I don't know if I need modified something more in the server. I think I have something wrong (or missing) in the persistence.xml or openejb.xml

Comment: I am not expert in openejb. However in persistence.xml you can't use both attributes `jta-data-source` and `non-jta-data-source` referring to the same dataSource. Try to remove the second one. Are you following a tutorial??

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake, for `non-jta-data-source` I used the dataSource db2.

I was following the tutorial
    [link] http://javanotebook.com/2007/09/28/openejb_3_and_tomcat_6.html
    
Then googling, because the modification of openejb.xml is not explicated there.

Thanks perissf for your effort

Answer (score 0):

The version of OpenEJB you're using is 4 years old.  I don't think we added JSF support till version 3.1 -- if I recall correctly.

I really recommend you try the latest version of the Tomcat/OpenEJB stack, TomEE http://openejb.apache.org/download.html.

We basically took the code you're using and completed all the features and got it through the Java EE 6 TCK and officially certified it.  We changed the name as calling it "Tomcat/OpenEJB" is a bit misleading for a certified server. but it's all the same developers and same code (well better version of the code ... perhaps better version of the developers too :).

Comment: Thanks David Blevins for your reply. I didn't know that version was so old and it didn't support JSF.
But I have another problem now :S... maybe you can help me.   

I tried with the version of TomEE 1.0.0, but I can not run it because:   

`code
GRAVE: Excepción enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.apache.openejb.jsf.CustomApplicationFactory`   

Do you know if this version support JSF 2.0?

Thanks in advance

Comment: JSF 2.0 is supported. Post as a new question and I'll follow up. We should be able to get it working.

Comment: You probably just need to remove the JSF implementation from the app and use the one in the server.

Comment: Hello David,


   What means exactly remove the JSF implementation from the app and use the one in the server?


   Modify `<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>` in my web.xml file?


Sorry for this question, but I quite fresh in this web world :S.

Comment: Ahh David, I already posted this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202224/error-executing-tommee-1-0-with-jsf-2-0

Thanks a lot for your effort.