# Error executing TommEE 1.0 with JSF 2.0

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, openejb, apache-tomee

I'm trying use apache-tomee-1.0.0 with my JSF 2.0 web app... but I can't do it :(.

My problem is when I run the server logs this error:

```
30-ago-2012 18:49:39 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Excepción enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.apache.openejb.jsf.CustomApplicationFactory
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1585)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.apache.openejb.jsf.CustomApplicationFactory
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:379)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.openejb.jsf.CustomApplicationFactory
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:617)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:485)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.access$400(FactoryFinder.java:141)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:886)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:319)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:303)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:219)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:360)
    ... 15 more
```

Maybe I need modify any parameter in my web.xml???

I tried googling but I didn' find nothing to respect. Anybody can help me please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you have Mojarra in the webapp.  Is it possible you can try removing that and using the JSF implementation that comes with TomEE (that's MyFaces)?